# How to skip a certain line when reading a Java file using FileReader?

Tags: java, java-io

I am reading in a file like;

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(source);
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter((destination));

int char = 0;
while ((char = reader.read()) != -1) {
  writer.write(char);
}
```

Basically, I would like to first check if the source file contains a certain line, followed by a newline, and if so, I would like to skip these line from being written to the destination file.

Note the newline that I would like to skip would have been added to the source file using;

```
System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes()
```

Many thanks!

Comment: with readLine, only read the line and dont do anything with that line. Automatically skip to the next line with this.

Comment: Use BufferedReader with that uyou can use ReadLine() to read line and match that line with the format that you want to skip .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `BufferedReader`, which has a `readLine()` method. This will also make your code faster, due to the buffering, BTW.

Comment: Thanks @jb-nizet, just wondering what is the proper way to deal with newlines then - as BufferedWriter has no corresponding .writeLine(String) method ? is this correct? while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        bufferedWriter.write(inputLine);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
      }

Comment: You can use a PrintWriter on top of any other writer, and a PrintWriter has println() methods, which write the platform EOL. BufferedReader will deal with newlines, whatever is used: \r, \n or \r\n.